# After configuring Varnish how to cache the Web Page for 2 Minutes. (Ubuntu 14.04,Apache,PHP)

Tags: php, ubuntu, caching, varnish

I have run the below commands and put the source code into /var/www/html directory.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I have followed the below link for configuring the Varnish to cache the webpages.
But how do i know whether its cached or not. Everytime I open the webpage its showing the same webpage. How to set expiry for it.

I need to cache the webpage for 2 minutes and then expire, so where do I it set those duration.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3

This is what i get when I say

**curl -I http://localhost**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
ETag: "dd6d718cc03aac91085163fd1927f07a-gzip"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 13:17:48 GMT
X-Varnish: 1965452251 1965452250
Age: 13
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell if varnish is caching the page by looking at the HTTP headers returned from the request. The varnish request will have `Age: <seconds>` appended as a header to tell you the age of the request.

```
Via: 1.1 varnish-plus-v3
Via: 1.1 varnish-plus-v3
Age: 170
```

You can tell varnish how long to cache the response (if the proper cache headers aren't set on the response itself) by setting the `beresp.ttl` value [in the configuration file](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/increasing-your-hitrate.html) in vcl_backend_response (or vcl_fetch iirc, depending on your varnish version):

```
set beresp.ttl = 120s;
```

You can test this by doing

```
watch HEAD http://localhost:6081
```

which will repeat the HEAD request to show the headers from the URL every two seconds by default. You'll see Age: increasing until it crosses 120s, when the resource will be returned for the last time and expired from the cache (which means that you can see `Age: 122` even if it is set to 120s).

Test it with a value shorter than 120s to see it expire quicker.

Comment: hello MatsLindh its giving compilation error.
Unused sub vcl_backend_response, defined:
('input' Line 126 Pos 5)
sub vcl_backend_response {
Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
VCL compilation failed

Comment: As I mentioned, it depends on the version of Varnish you're using. In 3.x it should be within `vcl_fetch`.

Comment: its showing Age : some no.  But when i open the web page in fiddler and browser it should show approximately the same header age right ? But its different for me i tried curl in unix, fiddler, browser. All are showing different Ages when i open simultaneously in all.

Comment: Well - is it increasing or going down?

Comment: You can also use varnishlog and look at the log for your httpd to see if the request is actually propagated backwards or fetched from the internal cache.

Comment: its increasing and i changed the data db, so it should have been reflected on site but what ever is cached for the 1st time its still showing the same thing...

Comment: @Sharath That's the point of caching. If you change something in the database, you'll have to expire the cache or wait for it to expire before it becomes visible. Varnish has bans for this.

Comment: Its a media based site. So not frequently the records gets added so we want to cache the pages for 2 minutes. So that any requests for site will be given from varnish. I want page to expire after 2 minutes so that new request will check in varnish and pull it freshly if it doesn't exit.   But for me after 2 minutes its still showing the old data.

Comment: Then you'll have to set the correct ttl. After that the object should be expired. The Age should then be reset. If it isn't, verify that the configuration is the currently running configuration, that it shouldn't be set in a different location and use varnishlog to confirm the values returned to the clients.

Comment: @Sharath did find the answer for you? Can you accept this answer as the answer by maybe editing in some of the comment answers?

Comment: No problem. I stumbled on the question and thought I'd ask. Happy Friday!